# Diophantine equation has at least $k$ positive integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

$k$ is a positive integer. Could we find all the pairs of positive integers $(a,b)$ such that the Diophantine equation
$$x(x+a)=y(y+b)$$
has at least $k$ positive integer solutions $(x,y)$, that is $x,y$ are all positive integers?

For example, $a=2(k+1)+\dfrac{(2k+2)!!}{2k+2},b=\dfrac{(2k+2)!!}{2k+2}-2(k+1)$. I find it luckily , without System approach

This problem's background is the 2014 China Mathematical Olympaid P2 problem. The exam is only want **a** pair $(a,b)$. So, I want to find **all** pairs $(a,b)$.

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of solutions for some given $a, b$?

Comment: Since there are infinitely many such pairs, what do you mean by "find"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael  analytic expression give all such $a,b$ ?

Comment: Could you give us some background or context for this question, such as what you have tried, where you have got stuck, and where this question comes from?

Comment: @OldJohn Thanks a lot! I have edit the problem

Comment: So - what have you tried so far, and where have you got stuck?

Comment: @OldJohn I have just find some $(a,b)$, But don't know how to compute all

Comment: Well, perhaps you could add the results you have found to the question? And maybe the methods you used to find them?

Comment: @OldJohn Thank you very much!  For example, $a=2(k+1)+\dfrac{(2k+2)!!}{2k+2},b=\dfrac{(2k+2)!!}{2k+2}-2(k+1)$. I find it luckily , without System approach

Answer (score 4):

$x(x+a) = (x+\frac a2)^2-\frac{a^2}4$, so $x(x+a)=y(y+b)$ if and only if
$$\left(x+\frac a2\right)^2-\left(y+\frac b2\right)^2=\frac{a^2-b^2}{4}$$
if and only if
$$(2x+2y+a+b)(2x-2y+a-b)=(a+b)(a-b). $$
So if we let $c=a+b, d=a-b$, then any factorization of $cd$ into factors $c'd'$ of the same parity (i.e. $c'\equiv c\pmod 2$, $d'\equiv d\pmod 2$) gives rise to the solution $x=\frac{c'-c+d'-d}{2}$, $y=\frac{c'-c+d-d'}{2}$. And if $c'>c$ and $c'-c>|d'-d|$ these solutions are positive, and if $c>|d|\ge0$ then also $a,b>0$.

For $k>0$ let $c=3^{k+1}$, $d=3^{k}$. Then for $0< i\le k$ we can let $c'=3^{k+1+i}$, $d'=3^{k-i}$, that is with
$$ a=\frac{3^{k+1}+3^{k}}2=2\cdot 3^{k}, \qquad b=\frac{3^{k+1}-3^{k}}2=3^{k}$$
we have at least the $k$ solutions
$$ x=\frac{3^{k+1+i}-3^{k+1}-3^{k-i}+3^k}{2}, \qquad  y=\frac{3^{k+1+i}-3^{k+1}+3^{k-i}-3^k}{2}$$

Comment: Of course $3$ can be replaced by any odd integer $\ge 3$.
Another special case is $a=b$, where you have infinitely many positive integer solutions $x=y$.